# if between 2 hours, straddling midnight

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I've tried searching the internet for this, but I'm coming up blank.

Basically, I has this:

```
If Hour(Now()) >= 8 And Hour(Now()) < 17 then response.write("TEST")
```

This will show the word TEST between 8am and 5pm - but I want it to be able straddle midnight.

I want to be able to say, if the time is between 10pm and 4am then show something.

I'm using Classic ASP - is there anyone who can help me - I'm going nuts!

At the moment, I'm simply putting the statement twice - like this;

```
If Hour(Now()) >= 22 And Hour(Now()) < 23 then response.write("TEST")
If Hour(Now()) >= 0 And Hour(Now()) < 4 then response.write("TEST")
```

That works, but there must be a way of doing it without having to do 2 if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - so I had to write my own function:

```
function timeLimit(startTime, endTime)
    h=hour(now())
    if startTime>endTime then
        if h>=startTime or h<=endTime then
            timeLimit=True
        else
            timeLimit=False
        end if
    elseif startTime<endTime then
        if h>=startTime and h<=endTime then
            timeLimit=True
        else
            timeLimit=False
        end if
    else
        if h=startTime then
            timeLimit=True
        else
            timeLimit=False
        end if
    end if
end function
```

This will work out if the start time number is greater that the end time number - if it is, then it must span midnight. It will then act accordingly - returning either true or false, dependent on inputs.

So, if I wanted to display the words "Hello World" between 8pm and 2pm, I would use this:

```
if timeLimit(20, 14) then Response.Write "Hello World"
```

If I wanted to show "Hello World" between 8am and 5pm, I would use this:

```
if timeLimit(8, 17) then Response.Write "Hello World"
```

If I only wanted to show "Hello World" at 4pm, I would use this:

```
if timeLimit(16, 16) then Response.Write "Hello World"
```

I hope that helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
Dim h
    h = Hour(Now())
    If h >= 22 Or h < 4 Then Response.Write("Test")
```

Or

```
If Hour(DateAdd("h", 2, Now)) < 6 Then Response.Write("test")
```

Or

```
Select Case Hour(Now())
    Case 22,23,0,1,2,3 : Response.Write("test")
End Select
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Echo CStr(InTime("02:00", "18:00"))
WScript.Echo CStr(InTime("18:00", "22:00"))
WScript.Echo CStr(InTime("15:00", "04:00"))

Function InTime(ByVal startTime, ByVal endTime)
Dim thisTime
    thisTime  = CDate(FormatDateTime(Now(), vbShortTime))
    startTime = CDate(startTime)
    endTime   = CDate(endTime)
    If endTime < startTime Then endTime = DateAdd("h", 24, endTime)
    InTime = ( thisTime >= startTime And thisTime <= endTime )
End Function
```

Comment: Those are good ideas... and they will arok as a work around, but I'm really after a way of only having to give a start and end time as variables and then have the code work it out. I'm wondering if maybe a function is the way to go?